# How to fetch value of variable of variable (parameter expansion) in unix?

Tags: linux, unix

How to fetch value of variable of variable (parameter expansion) in unix?

I have a text file(comma separated) filename='workdir.txt' as below which I am reading in unix shell script:

```
$AC_WORKDIR,current,FILE

$AC_WORKDIR,1 week,DIR
```

and so on

`$AC_WORKDIR` is env varriable `AC_WORKDIR="/home/ascxd01/data/workdir"` already defined.

My code is as below:

```
filename='workdir.txt'

while read line; do

work_dir=`echo $line | cut -d',' -f1`

echo "$work_dir"

done< $filename
```

When I am doing `echo "$work_dir"` its giving me `$AC_WORKDIR` however I want the actual value of `$AC_WORKDIR` which is `"/home/ascxd01/data/workdir"`

Please tell me how to do it.

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251893/get-environment-variable-by-variable-name

Comment: You probably need the `bash` flag.

Comment: I am using echo "${!work_dir}" but still not working

Comment: try this: eval "echo $work_dir"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you drop the leading `$` the indirect expansion should work normally, eg.

```
while read line; do
    work_dir=`echo $line | cut -d',' -f1 | tr -d '$'` # delete "$"
    echo "${!work_dir}"
done< $filename
```

The linked answer provides other maybe less good alternatives that would work, like `eval "echo $work_dir"`.